# Access class n from inside itself

Tags: java, multithreading, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a sorting method inside a custom list object that is set up to run repeatedly every `long n` milliseconds. The problem is, after it sorts a copy of the list in the background, I need to update the original list back to it.
My code:

```
copy = (SortedList<?>) super.clone();
Collections.sort(copy);
super.SortedList=copy;
Thread.sleep(millisTimeInterval);
```

How do I then set the original class that this is a method of to copy? It does extend ArrayList.

Comment: You need to set what? You are sorting a copy so I do not understand what original list you need to set back.

Comment: I need to set the original that the copy is contained in to the copy

Comment: You can't magically turn one object into another. If you want to replace a reference with a new one, you'll probably want to do that from outside the object.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I’ll probably end up implementing a sort manually so the whole list doesn’t have to be locked anyways.

Comment: If you're on Java 8+, you might consider using a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of rolling your own concurrency logic.

Comment: The problem is there may be a lot of mutative operations being applied to the array list.